# How to extract node value from elements with same name but different attribute values in PHP using DOMDocument?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have the following XML data :

```
    <item>     
       <category domain="disease">Ebola</category>
       <category domain="location">Liberia</category>
    </item>
```

I tried :

```
 $category=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item')->getElementsByTagName('category');
 $domain=$category->getAttribute('domain');
```

However, it gave me a fatal error.

Comment: You use `getElementsByTagName` so you get a list back not an element. So loop over the list first before you call `getAttribute`

Comment: Do you mean like this:                                                               for($j=0;$j<2;++$j){
    $category=$y->getElementsByTagName('category');
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ("looping");
    echo ("<br>");
  }
  $domain=$category->getAttribute('domain');

Comment: Don't really see where `$y` comes from. Just `foreach` over the nodeList returned by `getElementsByTagName`.